# What is the best way to check if the contract has experienced sandwich attacks

Tags: txpool, frontrunning, tools, mev

I am searching for a convenient way or tool to see if the contract was exploited by frontrunners. I have several smart contracts that expose functions that are suspect to these so-called sandwich attacks. Particularly, I am interested in past attempts to sandwich these functions. Is there a convenient way to analyze this without much overhead, like looking at Etherscan txs one by one and trying to find it manually?

Answer (score 0):

I investigated this for Uniswap V2 transactions and found that [Forta](https://forta.org) provides great infrastructure for this. Here is repo for my [Uniswap V2 Sandwich Attack Detector](https://github.com/j2abro/UniswapV2-Sandwich-Attack-Detector). I published this as a Forta agent/bot that detects transactions in real time, but in the development environment you can run the agents with past transactions which might provide what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Sandwiched.wtf is a tool that lets users check whether they ever fell victim to such an attack.